# Whats the best way to share objects between webservers on different hosts

Tags: node.js, express, load-balancing

TLDR;
I am wondering what is the best way to reliably share an object or other data between n number of webservers on n number of machines?

I have looked at the likes of redis but it seems that this would not be what I am actually looking for here. I am now thinking that something like IPC over remote / RPC might be more appropriate? Is there a better way to do this given it will be called at minimum 10 times over a 30 second interval which can exponentially grow as the number of users running servers grows too.

Example & current use case:

I run a multiplayer mod for a game which receives a decent level of traffic and we are starting to notice cases where requests get dropped sometimes. The backend webserver is written in NodeJS and uses express in a couple of places too. We are in the process of restructuring the system and we have now come to restructuring the part of the system that handles a heartbeat from each server that members of the public host. This information is then shared out to the players so they can decide which server to join.

Based on my own research I am looking to host the service on several different machines for redundancy. These machines are then linked over vlan / vswitch so that they have a secure method to communicate with eachother. The database system is already setup to replicate this way however I cannot see a performance inclined way to handle the sharing of objects containing information about the servers that have communicated with each webhost.

If it helps the system works something like this:

`Users server -> my load balancer -> webhost (backend).`

`Player -> my load balancer -> webhost (backend) returns info on all currently online servers.`

In the example above and what is currently in use is a single instance webserver which handles the requests and processes needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea while the community proposes answers: consider reading about Apache Thrift. It is not such as IPC like, but more an RPC like. If the architecture of your servers, or the different components or the "backend network" is in "star"... with one "master" I shoud consider that possibility.

If the architecture of your backend is not like that... but a group of "independent" entities, it comes to my mind to solve the functionality with some "data bus" such as private MQTT broker and a group of members, subscribed or publishing data for the rest of the network. The most optimal serialization strategy for the object would be in my opinion Google Protobuf.

The integration of Mqtt with nodeJS is very simple, and if the weight of the packets is not too big, and you can admit some latency, I would really recommend you to make some tests using Mqtt with a publish/subscription QoS=2. It would not take great efforts to substitute de underlying communications library that you are using.

Once that is said, it seems that there's another solution: Kafka, that seems very interesting (I don't really know it).

Your choice will depend on the nature of your data, mostly: weight of the packets, frequency per user, and the latency you are willing to admit for the worst of the scenarios.

Comment: Well, it seems that you were the only one to reply, for that I am greatful!

So with taking your advice and comments I did do some further digging and research and it does seem that what you have suggested is likely to be the best way forward. 

What I have gone for is to create a Master-Slave system with an elect process for in the event that a master goes down. This is also backed up with a DB to help reduce the chance of data loss. (This is also hosted on all nodes whether they are Master or Slave).